# How can I know the API that a site uses?

Tags: ajax, wordpress, rest, api, plugins

I have to find what API are using in a website.
I guess it is possible to find in a inspector, but I do not found it.

Could you help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]You can see the API urls consumed by your application by inspecting the page in the Network section. Reload the page and you will have all the urls